# php function last_insert_id() is not working with REPLACE INTO query

Tags: php, mysql, lastinsertid

I am using REPLACE INTO query to insert in to table but after executing query by using mysql_query() function and if I use last_insert_id() it is only giving me 0 value.

why this is happening so? and how can I overcome this behavior.

:Pankaj

Answer (score 4):

You could try using `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` instead. It accomplishes the same thing as `REPLACE INTO`, but in a single server-side operation. `REPLACE INTO` can end up causing two operations: delete the old one, insert the new one.

But regardless of the query type, you do have to ensure that the table's primary key is an `auto_increment` field. last_insert_id() does not work properly otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

`REPLACE INTO` doesn't seem to affect the vaue that can be obtained via `last_insert_id()`.

It seems to be the expected behavior, judging from this :

- [`LAST_INSERT_ID()` give wrong value after `REPLACE INTO` query](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=35116)
- [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: That applies if you specify the value for the auto-increment field (i.e. turning off the magic ;-)). Is that the case with your queries, PankajK?